# How to connect Macbook pro's Retina screen with my Mac mini?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, mac-mini

I want to use my Macbook Pro as a screen of my Mac mini(with both OS X and Bootcamp Windows).
I've following cables:
 1. Thunderbolt to Ethernet
 2. Thunderbolt to VGA

Any possible solution?

Comment: Maybe Screen Sharing will do the trick? https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14148?viewlocale=en_US&locale=es_MX

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to run a Macbook Pro in Target Display Mode, only iMacs.

Ref: Apple KB - [Target Display Mode: Frequently Asked Questions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

BTW, VGA or Ethernet to Thunderbolt is a physical impossibility.
Your cables must be  Thunderbolt to VGA / Ethernet.